# Inter process communication using FIFO

Tags: linux

Client server must pass to the Server process a filename and the Server process must return the number of lines in the file. My problem is that the received variable only contains 6 characters of the filename and it ends up by throwing segmentation fault dump core error. Do you know why this happens? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int fd1,fd2;

    const char *fifo1="./fifo1Channel";
    const char *fifo2="./fifo2Channel";
    mkfifo(fifo1,0666);
    mkfifo(fifo2,0666);
    char filename[30];
    printf("Give me a filename:\n");
    fgets(filename,30,stdin);
    strtok(filename,"\n");
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid>0){
        char received[30], ch;
        FILE *fp;
        fd1=open(fifo1, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd1,received,strlen(received));
        close(fd1);
        printf("From server process:%s\n",received);
        fp=fopen(received,"r");
        int nrOfLines=0;
        for(ch=getc(fp);ch!=EOF;ch=getc(fp))
            if(ch=='\n')
                nrOfLines++;
        fd2=open(fifo2, O_WRONLY);
        write(fd2,&nrOfLines,sizeof(nrOfLines));
        close(fd2);
        return 0;
    }
    if(pid==0){
        int receivedNumber;
        fd1=open(fifo1,O_WRONLY);
        write(fd1,filename,strlen(filename));
        close(fd1);
        fd2=open(fifo2,O_RDONLY);
        read(fd2,&receivedNumber,sizeof(receivedNumber));
        close(fd2);
        printf("From  client process: %d\n",receivedNumber);
        return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in server process. I replaced strlen(received) with 30, the maximum number of characters of filename, in function read and it works now!